# Compare two files and matched line send to new file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have two files

file1.txt

```
a|1|cd
a|2|cd
a|4|cd
```

file2.txt

```
a|0001|hj|df
a|0002|ed|nb
a|0003|vf|za
a|0004|er|ns
a|0005|oi|lk
```

I need a create new file with the lines matched by de second column of the files, I try by then next code

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$2]++;next} a[$2] ' file1.txt file2.txt
```

but no found records, because file1.txt in second column doesn't contain 0 at the left I have the instruction

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$(printf("%09d\n", $2))]++;next} a[$2]'
```

but doesn't work.

The result must be:

file3.txt

```
a|0001|hj|df
a|0002|ed|nb
a|0004|er|ns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding zero to field forces awk to treat it as a number, not a string:

```
$ awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$2+0]++;next} a[$2+0] ' file1.txt file2.txt
a|0001|hj|df
a|0002|ed|nb
a|0004|er|ns
```

As a string `0001` is different from `1`.  By adding zero to each, we convert them to numbers which results in the comparison that you want.

Comment: [$2+0]++ is for convert string to number ??? @John1024

Comment: @MiguelAngel `$2+0` forces awk to treat `$2` as a number, not a string.   The `++` part of this command is separate and unrelated.